# jquery create a unique id

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a.menuitem').click(function() {
      var arr = 0;
      var link = $( this ), url = link.attr( "href" );
      var newDiv = $( document.createElement( 'div' ) )
      $( "#content_pane" ).append( newDiv );
      newDiv.load( url );
      return false;
  });
});
```

As you can see I am creating a `div` and adding some content to it, how would I give each `div` that is created a unique id, something like section1, section2, section3, etc?

Comment: Why do you need this?  Can't you pass the node around instead of its ID?

Comment: I need it becuase if I just have it creating <div> then I have no way of getting the correct div when it comes to be deleted

Comment: I don't understand.  How would you get the ID, then?

Comment: @sico87: strager brings up a valid point. There are nicer ways than creating phony `id` values. If you don't like saving a reference to the element, how about using its position within its parent as an index into the list of divs you're creating here?

Comment: Some commonly third party libraries only accept an element ID (& sadly not a reference - limiting with SaaS scripts). mar10's suggestion below (for jQuery 1.9+) is ideal in that case.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Just use a counter:

```
var section = 1;
$(function() {
  $("a.menuitem").click(function() {
    ...
    $("<div></div>").attr("id", "section" + section++).appendTo("#content_pane");
    ...
    return false;
  });
});
```

Also, I'd suggest creating the element as per above.

Answer (score 17):

Starting with jQuery 1.9 UI there is a `$().uniqueId()` function, that sets a unique id attribute (if no id is already defined):

http://api.jqueryui.com/uniqueId/

(Note that this requires jQueryUI on top of jQuery.)

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect, I didn't know about this function. Use case: Integration with 3rd party map library that requires an element ID to be passed. With this I can just loop for each element which I've tagged as being a map and call this to assign ID's to them to then pass to the map libs init method.

Comment: That's jQuery UI, a user interface library running on top of jQuery.

Comment: You're right, thanks, I will edit the answer to make this more clear

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't need to do this. If you can store the id in a variable, you could store the element itself *(well, a reference to the element)* in a variable too.

Comment: It is not practiacal to store the reference to the div object in some situations.

Comment: such as? my point is that you're going to be storing and passing around a string, just so you can get a reference to an element, you might as well pass the element itself.

Comment: How would I create multiple DIV's onclick in multiple variables? I need this beuase it is the only way, I could think of removing the element from the page onclick of a link

Comment: multiple variables? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Answer (score 3):

Now that Backbone.js has gained popularity, if you include it you automatically have access to [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org) just use: [Underscore: uniqueId](http://underscorejs.org/#uniqueId).

Or include it by itself, it's pretty lightweight and has some great functions