# How to create a new user ID for cloned element

Tags: javascript, jquery, uniqueidentifier, cloning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jquery create a unique id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817114/jquery-create-a-unique-id)

I am cloning a form and want to give a unique ID to each cloned element. How can I do this?

Here is my script:

```
     // Duplicates category select menu 

       $(".add-color").click(function(){
      $(".color-category").clone().removeClass('color-category').appendTo("#we-want-to").find('.submenu-select').addClass('hide');

    });


    $(".add-color-alternate").click(function(){
      $(".color-category-alternate").clone().removeClass('color-category-alternate').appendTo("#we-want-to").find('.submenu-select, .results-table').addClass('hide');

    });
```

HTML:

```
 <div id="we-want-to" class="sortable"></div>
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide us a JSFiddle of what you require?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
var i =1; 
 $(".add-color").click(function(){
         $(".color-category").clone().removeClass('color-category').attr('id',i++).appendTo("#we-want-to");
 });
```

Comment: You can't set the id to an integer. The first character of an id must be an alpha character.

Comment: html5 doctype allows for an integer.