# Finding out which input element user typed into

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page with multiple text inputs, and I want to determine which of the text inputs that the user is typing into. All of the text inputs are displayed with the same code. One big constraint is that I cannot modify the actual HTML code, so I cannot add IDs or classes to the input.

Here is what the HTML looks like:

```
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
```

Here is the code that I am using to detect a keypress:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
console.log(e.target) // will be the same for each input
});
```

Is there a way to distinguish between the different inputs. Is there an underlying DOM property that differentiates the text inputs such that I can access the inputs in constant time in the future(ie, does the DOM assign each input a unique id)?

Comment: You can use jQuery ui to create a unique id:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817114/jquery-create-a-unique-id.  `$('input').uniqueId();`

Comment: What do you need to do with this "id" to identify the element?

Comment: I want to be able to capture how the users interacted with a form in the future.

Comment: Have you tried selecting the element with jQuery .find() .children() and binding events? something like this:http://jsfiddle.net/aLXsp/1/

Comment: `e.target` returns the same element every time, regardless of which element is focused/active? Really? I'd suggest, perhaps, `document.activeElement`, but I'm really not quite sure what you're trying to do, or what's not working.

Answer (score 1):

On document load, you can loop through the input elements and make an "index" => "element" map. This can be used for constant time access in the future. The index of the map can act as the unique ID for the element.

I've put together a working fiddle for this. http://jsfiddle.net/fugHv/6/ . Does this solve your problem?

Here's the gist of the approach,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var inputMap = {}, inputArray = [];

    $.each($('input'), function(i, v){
        //Make an array of the inputs to ensure a constant time access
        inputArray.push(v);
        //Make a map of inputs with index as the key, for future use
        inputMap[i] = v; 
    });

    $('input').keypress(function(e){
        var pos = inputArray.indexOf(e.target);

        //This should provide the reference for the target input
        var inputRef = $(inputMap[pos]);
        ...
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can uniquely identify inputs using jQuery index method :

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
console.log(e.target) // will be the same for each input
console.log($(e.target).index());
});
```